# Bootstrap metro tile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want create a layout like this:

[image]

I want use a responsive layout and the square above must be a `metro tile`. Which class I should use for do this, I'm not an expert of `Bootrstrap`, someone could help me to make a rude example? thanks

Comment: Rude Example? Do you want us to be rude?

Comment: @PraveenKumar haah :) nope a simple example for show me how to get this structure.

Comment: Ha ha... Done. Check answer. `:)`

Comment: I can't just give you an example because i don't know how you want the tablet or mobile version to look. But i can give you a link where the bootstrap grid system is explained very well. http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use this...

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">Half</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">Half</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">Full</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">Half</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">Half</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the first two half isn't on the same row and the same for the last two

Comment: @SalvatoreFucito Check the output: **http://output.jsbin.com/yanijulaxi**. It's responsive too.

Comment: @praveen that's just a sucky example, you know there is a bit more too it than this..

Comment: @FrankW. The OP asked for a *rude* one. BTW, see the output here: **http://output.jsbin.com/yanijulaxi**. And tell me your view. Best is to use Flex Box.

Comment: Oh okay no problem, anyway this working for me! Thanks for the help :D

Comment: Well, it doesn't suck, it's a sucky example. Normally your would use the responsive grid system to make your website responsive. A good responsive website adapts to your device width.

I don't know what content you would like to use but normally your desktop version could look like the example praveen gave you, but on the mobile version the blocks would be stacked underneath eachother. So i would say that this example is not complete if you would like to make a responsive design. That's why i gave you a link where everything is explained clearly...

Comment: @FrankW. In my example, the link, I used `-xs-` classes to make sure it breaks down into tiles for mobile view too. `:)`

Comment: Allright, you just didn't in the answer you give on SO, but since the OP is satisfied with the answer and can move on with his code that's the main point of SO ;)